# A distribution as a linear combination of Dirac delta and its derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

This problem is from Exercise 1.13.22, Tao's *An Epsilon of Room*.

---

Let $\lambda$ be a distribution whose domain is the set of compactly supported smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

(i) Show that if $\lambda$ is a distribution and $n\ge 1$ is an integer, then $\lambda x^n=0$ iff $\lambda$ is a linear combination of $\delta$ and its first $n-1$ derivatives $\delta', \delta'', ...,\delta^{(n-1)}$.

(ii) Show that a distribution $\lambda$ is supported on ${0}$ iff it is a linear combination of $\delta$ and finitely many of its derivatives.

---

My attempt: For both (i) and (ii), the 'if' parts are easy, and I already did them easily. The problems are the 'only if' parts.

For the 'only if' part of (i), I let $a_i = (-1)^i \dfrac{\lambda(x^i)}{i!}$, and tried to prove that $\lambda= \sum_{i=0} ^{n-1}a_i \delta^{(i)}$, but I don't know how to proceed further.

For the 'only if' part of (ii), I don't have any idea to proceed.

Does anyone have ideas?

Any hints or advices will help a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Given any smooth $f$, you can write, using the Taylor polynomial, 
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\,x^k\ + \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi(x))}{n!}\,x^{n}.
$$
Now, when you apply $\lambda$ to the last term, you get (by definition of multiplication)
$$
\left\langle \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi(x))}{n!}\,x^{n},\lambda \right\rangle
=\left\langle \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi(x))}{n!},\lambda x^{n} \right\rangle=0.
$$
Thus
$$
\langle f,\lambda\rangle=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\langle x^k,\lambda\rangle}{k!}\,(-1)^k\langle f,\delta^{(k)}\rangle,
$$
and
$$
\lambda = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\langle x^k,\lambda\rangle}{k!}\,(-1)^k \delta^{(k)}.
$$

The second question looks less trivial. [Here](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/distns_at_zero.pdf) is a proof.